# How to check all sublists for a set of required elements

Tags: python, list, function, methods, sublist

A list will contain 9 sublists of 9 numbers.
Each sublist must contain the numbers 1-9 in any order (i.e. there must be no repetition/missing numbers.)
How to check this condition is met?

valid_list would return true, invalid_list would return false.

```
valid_list = 
       [[1,3,5,7,9,8,6,4,2],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[5,4,3,2,1,9,8,7,6],
        [1,3,5,7,9,8,6,4,2],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[5,4,3,2,1,9,8,7,6],
        [1,3,5,7,9,8,6,4,2],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[5,4,3,2,1,9,8,7,6]]

invalid_list =
   [[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2],[9,8,7,7,7,7,6,5,6],
    [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2],[9,8,7,7,7,7,6,5,6],
    [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2],[9,8,7,7,7,7,6,5,6]]
```

I am sure that all() can do this, but I can't figure out how. I have tried many things like..

```
lists = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 6, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 6, 8, 9]]
all(x in [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]] for x in list in lists)
>>>(Would return true if not erroneous)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use the `sort` function and compare the result with the list containing 1 to 9

```
  def check_duplicated(lst):
        for l in lst:
            if sorted(l) != list(range(1, 10)):
                return False
        return True
```

Comment: While sitting at work today, a colleague suggested this method also, so I rushed home and tried it out with success! 
I now realise that there are many ways this could have been done, but as a novice I couldn't see the way. 
Thanks for this, and other proposed solutions

Answer (score 0):

```
lists = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 6, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 6, 8, 9]]
all([[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] == sorted(el) for el in lists])
```

As an extension, although you didn't ask for it, you can choose to accept repetition but reject missing numbers by converting each `list` in `lists` to a `set` and back to a `list`.

```
all([[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] == sorted(list(set(el))) for el in lists])
```

Answer (score 0):

I would define a validator function to validate a sublist first. Then call this validator using all().

Eg.

```
def isValidList(myList):
    return True if len(set(myList)) == 9 and max(myList) == 9 and min(myList) == 1 else False

## returns True if all sublists are valid
all(isValidList(subList) for subList in some_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove repetition from the inner list by converting to a [set](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=set#set-types-set-frozenset), then checking that set matches the valid set of numbers

```
valid_list = [
    [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 8, 6, 4, 2],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
    [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 9, 8, 7, 6],
    [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 8, 6, 4, 2],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
    [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 9, 8, 7, 6],
    [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 8, 6, 4, 2],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
    [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 9, 8, 7, 6],
]


invalid_list = [
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2],
    [9, 8, 7, 7, 7, 7, 6, 5, 6],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2],
    [9, 8, 7, 7, 7, 7, 6, 5, 6],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2],
    [9, 8, 7, 7, 7, 7, 6, 5, 6],
]


def validate_lists(lists):
    valid_set = set(range(1, 10))
    return all(set(list_) == valid_set for list_ in lists)

print(validate_lists(valid_list) == True)
print(validate_lists(invalid_list) == False)
```